# Pyautogui locateonscreen gives wrong coordinates

Tags: python, pyautogui

I worte a script in Python 3.8.5 order to automate my job. It was worked properly for a long time. But after new installation of my windows does not anymore. The problem is pyautogui gives back wrong values. For example picture at the point (1700,900) give back (0,45). That is quite far from the right point.

```py
def verify_element_next_to(image,a,b,rec_jav,rec_jaf):

    count = 0
    while count < 10:    # 10* serach the picture
        try:
            img = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image, region=(0,0,rec_jav,rec_jaf),confidence = 0.5, grayscale = True)
            # a and b are coordinates points to be possible push the click away from the picture
            # rec = rectangle; jav = right under horizontal point , jaf = right under vertical point
            
            pyautogui.click(img[0]+a, img[1]+ b)  ## A click is pushed here away
            c = True
            print(image,' Found it!', img)           
        except:
            print(image, ' not found', count)
            time.sleep(1)
            count +=1
    c = False
```

Comment: Are you using multiple screens?

Comment: Your confidence is quite low and how large is the image you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I am using multiple monitor, but before I start the script I  always left only one. 
The large of the pictures are various from 5*5mm up to 30*30mm.